# MySQL/Writing file error (Errcode 28)

Tags: mysql, logging

I have the following error with one of our web applications -

```
Query3 failed: Error writing file '/tmp/MY1fnqpm' (Errcode: 28) ... INSERT MailList... (removed the rest of the query for security reasons)
```

Any ideas - is this some hard disk space issue on my server?

Comment: Is there sufficient disk space available?

Comment: Free up some space on your device.

Comment: I had this error pop up today on a device with only 11% used.  I rebooted the machine, and it was fine after that, but it would seem that this error can happen even when there is space available.

Comment: As pointed above Error code 28 means that there's insufficient disk space. Please note that it's a server error message, not client. So make sure you're checking on the right server.

Comment: It could be caused, as others pointed out, by a lack of free space on the device. Another reason could be denied write access to the mount point.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use the [`perror` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/perror.html):

```
$ perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

Unless error codes are different on your system, your file system is full.

Comment: "your file system is full". On which side? db server or db client?

Comment: it is on the db_server. you can use `while true; do df -h /tmp; sleep 3; done` while running the script to see how much space is used by temporary tables.

Answer (score 25):

We have experienced similar issue, and the problem was MySQL used /tmp directory for its needs (it's default configuration). And /tmp was located on its own partition, that had too few space for big MySQL requests.

For more details take a look for this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716778/994302

Answer (score 22):

I had same problem but disk space was okay (only 40% full).
Problem were inodes, I had too many small files and my inodes were full.

You can check inode status with df -i

Answer (score 12):

The error means that you dont have enough space to create temp files needed by MySQL.

The first thing you can try is to expand the size of your `/tmp/` partition. If you are under LVM, check the `lvextend` command.

If you are not able to increase the size of your partition `/tmp/` you can work in the MySQL configuration, **edit the `my.cnf`** (typically on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) file and look for this line:

`tmpdir = /tmp/`

Change it for whatever you want (example `/var/tmp/`). Just be sure to have space and assign write permission for the mysql user in the new directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't have this line "tmpdir = /tmp/" in my my.cnf ?

Answer (score 4):

Run the following code:

du -sh /var/log/mysql

Perhaps mysql binary logs filled the memory, If so, follow the removal of old logs and restart the server. Also add in my.cnf:

expire_logs_days = 3

Comment: du: cannot access `/var/log/mysql': No such file or directory

Comment: should be `du -sh /var/log/mysql.log`

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you don't have enough space in the partition. Usually MYSQL uses /tmp on linux servers. This may happen with some queries because the lookup was either returning a lot of data, or possibly even just sifting through a lot of data creating big temp files.

Edit your /etc/mysql/my.cnf

> tmpdir = /your/new/dir

e.g

> tmpdir = /var/tmp

Should be allocated with more space than /tmp that is usually in it's own partition.

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who don't have a full disk or full inodes and that are using MySQL 8, you should take a look at your /var/lib/mysql directory to check if there is some large ***binlog.XXXXXX*** files.

It was the case for me and it prevented a query to be executed until the end because it seemed like this query was generating a large binlog file.

I just had to turn off the logbin generation by adding this parameter in */etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf* :

```
disable_log_bin
```

Then restart mysql service :

```
service mysql restart
```

After that i didn't have the "No space left on device" error anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and the problem was simply not enough space on my virtual machine. I deleted some unnecessary files and it started working again.

my
memory/disk space allocation looked something like this

```
df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   37G   37G  127M 100% /
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using this line if the other doesn't work:

du -sh /var/lib/mysql/database_Name

You may also want to check with  your host and see how big they allow your databases to be.

Answer (score 0):

For xampp users: on my experience, the problem was caused by a file, named '0' and located in the 'mysql' folder. The size was tooooo huge (mine exploded to about 256 Gb). Its removal fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Today. I have same problem... my solution:

1) check inode: `df -i`
I saw:

```
root@vm22433:/etc/mysql# df -i
Filesystem Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev 124696 304 124392 1% /dev
tmpfs 127514 452 127062 1% /run
/dev/vda1 1969920 1969920 0 100% /
tmpfs 127514 1 127513 1% /dev/shm
tmpfs 127514 3 127511 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 127514 15 127499 1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs 127514 12 127502 1% /run/user/1002
```

2) I began to look what folders use the maximum number of inods:

```
 for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

soon I found in /home/tomnolane/tmp folder, which contained a huge number of files.

3) I removed /home/tomnolane/tmp folder
PROFIT.

4) checked:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            124696    304  124392    1% /dev
tmpfs           127514    454  127060    1% /run
/dev/vda1      1969920 450857 1519063   23% /
tmpfs           127514      1  127513    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           127514      3  127511    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           127514     15  127499    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           127514     12  127502    1% /run/user/1002
```

it's ok.

5) `restart mysql service` - it's ok!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after little research found that the snap directory was occupying most of the space. So executed following command to get rid of it:

`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`

After that ran following command to get rid of useless/dev/loop mounts:

```
`sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools`
```

After that ran following command to restart mysql:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

It worked for me!