# MySQL - create table error 3 [HY000]

Tags: mysql, database, putty, database-table

Slowly but surely I am getting the hang of the command line methods rather than using the GUI, but I seem to be failing at creating tables in my database.

I'm getting the following error code:

```
ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file './10081552/people.frm' (Errcode: 28)
```

From some research I've performed, it normally means that there is no space, but I find that hard to believe as its on my uni's server and I have created zero data as of yet.

I'm using a simple test table like:

```
mysql> create table person (person_id char(3), dob date);
```

It must be something I have missed rather than lack of space

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415710/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28

Comment: I found the suggested post upon initial search, but my question is how is this possible and if it is full how can I clear it?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple post, I noticed that other errors all have tmp in the directory but I noticed mine does not or am I missing something?

Comment: write query in sqlfiddle if you have doubt about query and check it.

Comment: Turns out that my lecturer messed up and I had no space. Thank you for your patience.