# Getting Error Code: 3. Error writing file (Errcode: 28) when doing a large query

Tags: mysql, linux

When I try to do a large query (such as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23381855/1070958 )  Im getting this:

Error Code: 3. Error writing file '/tmp/MYYQVeZr' (Errcode: 28)

Its not a space issue or a permission issue either:

[image: proof]

What is wrong?

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear.  There is a problem writing an intermediate temporary result.  This would be a space issue, a permissions issue, or a network issue.  There really isn't enough information to tell which it is.

Comment: uname -a says: Linux DiskStationVM 3.2.40 #34 SMP Sat Mar 8 17:08:43 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_bromolow_3612xs

Comment: I stated space available and also permission. I think there is more than enough information to discard at least 2 out of 3. And I can do your basic show tables so it isn't a network issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Turshija [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415710/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28) tells that:

If you have too many small files you may have inodes full. Check it with `df -i` in "IFree" or "IUse%" fields.

Isn't it your case?