# mySQL crashing due to /tmp full of PHP session files ..what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I run a fairly busy website that creates lots of session files in the /tmp folder. Recently I started getting this mySQL error:

```
MySQL said: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/MLX3o6NG' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
```

So I checked with `df -i` and found:

`/usr/tmpDSK             262144  262143         1  100% /tmp`

It looks like the inodes are full. What is the best thing I could do?

Move the PHP session files to another directory? If so, how? The `/` partition for example has `179691356` free inodes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415710/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have stated in your Post the /tmp directory is full.  However, you can redirect where your temp directory is writing to.

Go into your `my.cnf` file and look for something like this line:

`tmpdir = /tmp/`

If it is not there then add:

`tmpdir = /whatevr/dir/you/want`

Just be sure to have space in that directory and that Mysql has write permission for the new temp directory. Then restart your Mysql server for the changes to your `my.cnf` file to take affect...