# Cannot login into Phpmyadmin (user/pass is correct)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, server

I'm trying to login into my phpmyadmin but it keep getting redirected to the login page. I know user and password are correct because my website is still working properly and I can even connect to mysql using putty.

I noticed I'm getting "Cant create/write to file '/tmp/XXXXXXX' Errcode28" on one of my tables which apparently means lack of disk space so I deleted all the rows but it didn't resolve the issue.

I used `df -h` command and it says I have only used 13% of /dev/vdal1.

I don't even know where to start. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: yeah i probably can help.  so your not out of disk space then, and unles theres a setting to alot only certain disk space, thats not the issue. Clear all browser cache and cookes, and how do you have phpmyadmin setup?  Are you in your personal installation, or what, can you edit your main post with that info?  and comment back with the first answer?

Comment: a) Off-topic for Stack Overflow; better suited to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ b) Full `df -h` would be useful, along with relevant parts of your `my.cnf`; c) deleting things from MySQL does not reduce the size of the database under the default configuration. It *never* shrinks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415710/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for all those out there feeling helpless like me here is the solution:

1. SSH to your server
2. type `df -i` to see if your inode usage is full if yes
3. type `cd/`
4. type this:`echo -e "Inode count for`pwd`:\n"; /bin/ls -A|awk '{print "count=`find \""$0"\"|wc -l`; echo \""$0" \t\t $count\""}'|sh|awk '$NF != "1" {inode=$NF;$NF="";print "printf \"%-50s %8d\\n\" \""$0"\" \""inode"\""}'|sh && printf "%-50s %8d\n" "Total:" "`find ${pwd}|wc -l`"`

   this shows you which directory is using that space the most.
5. cd into that directory and repeat step 4 and 5 until you get to the directory that has the highest usage
6. clear as much as you can in that directory
7. reboot
8. enjoy :)