# failure to start rails application with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I am using my application on an aws server, today I reach the space limit and it showed me the following message `/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device` , I could increase the storage volume with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Brbqkzqvjw) but still cannot display my web page.
 by doing the following command `nginx -t` It show the following

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/nace.network/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/nace.network/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

my application is developed in ruby on rails 5 with passenger and nginx, previously it worked without any problem but I don't understand why it shows me that error

UPDATE:

I accessed the server again and it continues to send me the following warning:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

I execute the following command `df -h` and it shows me the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  364K  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       26G   15G  9.5G  62% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
```

and when use `tail -f log / production.log` into the project, it shows me the following error:

```
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.283374 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Started GET "/" for 190.198.232.67 at 2020-02-21 18:50:38 +0000
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.284158 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
D, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.285317 #12760] DEBUG -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]    (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`                                                                                               
D, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.355268 #12760] DEBUG -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]    (69.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `users`.`city` AS users_city FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`city`                           
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.355476 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms (ActiveRecord: 69.6ms)
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356099 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]   
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356136 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Error writing file '/tmp/MYkVaUQs' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device"): SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `users`.`city` AS users_city FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`city`):
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356157 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]   
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356179 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:12:in `index'
```

UPDATE 2

when executing the command `df -hP /tmp` I get this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overflow        1.0M  108K  916K  11% /tmp
```

it shows me that temp is a different partition and that it is 1 mb, what I have noticed is that the error appears only in the home where I make a query, I suppose that the data that it brings is larger than 1 mb . I'm looking for what to do to use the root for temporary files instead of the / temp partition but I haven't got the way to do it, according to [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431169&s=065ce86db61a7f7bcdd02532236cf1e8&p=8976725#post8976725) page I can disable them here /etc/fstab but I don't see the /temp line in the file, only this:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
```

Answer (score 0):

you tried to run the command with sudo?

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

or with sudo su

```
#service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, with "sudo" the server could be restarted without any problem, it no longer shows "fail" but the page still does not work, when accessing it it shows me the following message: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Comment: Could you run `$ df -hP /tmp` ? 

see the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415710/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28

Comment: I could find the problem, apparently the partition / temp is very small (1mb) and when making a query in the home it shows me the error, is there any way to make it take root for temporary files? I updated the post with more details

Comment: You should resize your /tmp partition  https://askubuntu.com/questions/199565/not-enough-space-on-tmp