# Incorrect key file for table error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table containing 14 million + rows. All varchar data. I am trying to run this query. I get output quickly. limit is set on 800K records only.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT unique_user_id, url, count(url) as url_visit_count, categories, count(categories) as count 
FROM ph_usertrack_data GROUP BY unique_user_id LIMIT 800000) a 
ORDER BY a.url_visit_count DESC LIMIT 100;
```

when I put limit to 1 million records, I get this error

`Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_6663_0.MYI'; try to repair it`

My temp folder is having a lot of space around 100 GB, so no space issue. Why this issue appears when I increase number of rows to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help-

> You can use df -h to check whether \tmp is in its own partition, and
>   how much space is allocated to it.
>
> If it is in its own partition and short of space, you can either:
>
> (a) modify /tmp so that its parition has more space (either by
>   reallocating or moving it to the main partition - e.g. see here) (b)
>   changing MySql config so that it uses a different temp folder on a
>   different partition, e.g. /var/tmp

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090073/mysql-incorrect-key-file-for-tmp-table-when-making-multiple-joins?rq=1) and [this](http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/a-fix-for-incorrect-key-file-for-table-mysql) too.

Comment: thanks I did the same. I also increased size of key buffer size from 16M to 256M